# Send Data Via Post Android to PHP

Tags: java, php, android, http-post

So, i'm trying to send message via Post in Android to PHP
here is the Android Java Function:

```
 //enviando para o backend
private void SendtoPHP(String reg) throws IOException {


    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://bubbledev.com.br/gcm/getdevice.php");

    try{
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", "" + reg ));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }

}
```

The PHP:

```
<?php       
include 'conecta.php';
$device_token  = urldecode($_POST['regid']);    
$sql = "INSERT INTO corposa.deviceandroid"
              . " (id,device_token)"
              . " VALUES (NULL,'$device_token')";
mysqli_query($con,$sql);
```

?>

The PHP is Just fine, I already tested it with a another Post and worked, but when the Android function tries $device_token dont recive any value and the SQL save a "" with the id at the table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use this code which is similar to yours, except the ResponseHandler.
It works for me.

```
HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", sID));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("etc", sETC));

try {           

    String SetServerString = "";

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://your-url.com/script.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();

    SetServerString = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);                

}  catch(Exception ex) {
    // failed
}
```

Comment: `NameValuePair` is now considered as deprecated by Android studio - here is a separate thread on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29220755/namevaluepair-deprecated

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but this is how I usually handle post requests from Android:

```
<?php
{
    $input = json_encode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    $deviceToken = $input->regId;
    mysqli_query($connection, "INSERT INTO corposa.deviceandroid (`id`, `device_token`) VALUES(NULL, '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($deviceToken) . "')";
}
```

Also, since you're using POST instead of GET, the data being passed to the server isn't url encoded, so urldecode isn't needed here.

Answer (score 0):

Code seems ok, only "strange" thing is:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
```

because you are adding only ONE BasicNameValuePair to the list. Maybe that is the problem...?

Answer (score 0):

I use this code in my current project, hope it's works for you too

```
  Map<String, String> kvPairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
    kvPairs.put("regid", reg);
    HttpClient httpclient = this.getNewHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://bubbledev.com.br/gcm/getdevice.php");
    if (kvPairs != null && kvPairs.isEmpty() == false) {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(kvPairs.size());
        String k, v;
        Iterator<String> itKeys = kvPairs.keySet().iterator();
        while (itKeys.hasNext()) {
            k = itKeys.next();
            v = kvPairs.get(k);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(k, v));
        }
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));
    }
    HttpResponse response;
    response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Also need this method in your class

```
public static HttpClient getNewHttpClient() {
    try {
        KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        trustStore.load(null, null);

        SSLSocketFactory sf = new RecorridoSSL(trustStore);
        sf.setHostnameVerifier(SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
        HttpProtocolParams.setContentCharset(params, HTTP.UTF_8);

        SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
        registry.register(new Scheme("http", PlainSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(), 80));
        registry.register(new Scheme("https", sf, 443));

        ClientConnectionManager ccm = new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params, registry);

        return new DefaultHttpClient(ccm, params);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return new DefaultHttpClient();
    }
}
```

hope I don't forgot anything, other way tell me

Answer (score 0):

Guys the error was in my PHP

```
$device_token  = urldecode($_POST['regid']);
```

This urldecode was messing out with my code haha

Thx for all help

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.project_name

import android.os.Bundle

import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import com.android.volley.Response

import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView)
        val url = "https://path/index.php"

        val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this)

        val stringRequest = object : StringRequest(
            Method.POST, url,
            Response.Listener { response ->
                textView.text = response!! // Changed 'e' to 'd' for debug logging
            },
            Response.ErrorListener { error ->
                textView.text = error.toString()
            }) {
            override fun getParams(): Map<String, String> {
                val params = HashMap<String, String>() // Use HashMap instead of deprecated HasMap
                params["key1"] = "hello" // No duplicate key
                params["key2"] = "world" // Added second key-value pair

                return params
            }

//            override fun getHeaders(): Map<String, String> {
//                return mapOf("Content-Type" to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") // Corrected case for header key
//            }
        }

        queue.add(stringRequest)
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).