# NameValuePair deprecated

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

since Android 22 NameValuePair is deprecated.

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/message/BasicNameValuePair.html) sends me to an article about openConnection, but that is what I do. So how is it replaced properly?

I know I can still use it and a string has to be build, just figuring how to pass data between methods.

Comment: I thought it was documentation bug from Google side. Because redirection destination does not match up with the purpose :|

Comment: I have no idea about Android, but it seems there are two issues here. Are you talking about somehow replacing NameValuePair (In what way? How do you use it?)? Or are you looking for a way to make HTTP requests? Please clarify your question without invalidating the answers.

Comment: Why do you bother about old items which you have no clue of? Yes, replacement would be the case, since it is deprecated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use ContentValues instead of list of NameValuePair.

Creating:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put("key1", "value1");
values.put("key2", 123);
```

Usage:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : values.valueSet()) {
    String key = entry.getKey();
    String value = entry.getValue().toString();
}
```

Comment: Which is just a wrapper around a `HashMap<String, Object>` to hold the actual values. Might as well just use that, as suggested in the other answer...

Comment: What about when you create an http connection like
new UrlEncodedFormEntity(values, HTTP.UTF_8);

It expects a NameValuePair, not ContentValues

Comment: @Dantalian UrlEncodedFormEntity is part of apache package together with NameValuePair. Whole packege is now deprecated, you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Why does android deprecate all the cool stuff?? Just joking, I will reimplement my deprecated code and happily reap the benefits!

Answer (score 5):

You could just use a

```
HashMap<String,Object>
```

and pass the HashMap b/w methods.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code, i use on my applications and works

```
 
public String post(JSONObject object) throws Exception {
```

HttpURLConnection conexao = null;

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO) {

        System.setProperty("http.keepAlive", "false");
    }

    try {

        URL url = new URL(URL_WEB_SERVICE_POST);

        conexao = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conexao.setConnectTimeout(20000);
        conexao.setReadTimeout(15000);
        conexao.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conexao.setDoInput(true);
        conexao.setDoOutput(true);

        Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                .appendQueryParameter("parametros", object.toString());

        String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

        conexao.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(query.getBytes().length);

        OutputStream os = conexao.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

        writer.write(query);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        conexao.connect();

        int responseCode = conexao.getResponseCode();

        Log.v(Debug.TAG + " reponseCode", String.valueOf(responseCode));

        if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            try{

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conexao.getInputStream()));
                String linha;

                while ((linha = br.readLine())!= null){

                    sb.append(linha);
                }

                return sb.toString();
            }catch (Exception e){

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }else{

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CLIENT_TIMEOUT){

                throw new Exception("Tempo maximo na comunição atingido: "+ conexao.getErrorStream());
            }
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new Exception("Falha de comunicação, verifique sua conexão com a internet");
    }finally {

        conexao.disconnect();
    }

    return null;
}

Comment: my app isn't on Play, unfortunately i need to support old devices. A lot of users in company still have old devices.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [Volley](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html), an HTTP library that makes networking for Android apps easier and most importantly, faster.

Answer (score 1):

Use Java `HttpUrlConnection` With a `Map`/`Hashmap` , if you don't want to use the Apache library as legacy.

```
/**
 *
 * @param postUrl
 * @param postParams
 * @return response in string
 */
public static String makeServiceCall(final String postUrl, final Map<String, String> postParams) {
    Log.e("URL#",postUrl);
    StringBuilder responseBuilder  = new StringBuilder();
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try {
        final URL mUrl = new URL(postUrl);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) mUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android-4.0.3; en-us; Galaxy Nexus Build/IML74K) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) CrMo/16.0.912.75 Mobile Safari/535.7");
        conn.connect();
        conn.setReadTimeout(180000);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(180000);
        final OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(getQuery(postParams));
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();
        final int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            String line;
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                responseBuilder.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            responseBuilder.append("");
        }
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseBuilder.append(e.getMessage());
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        responseBuilder.append(e.getMessage());
        return responseBuilder.toString();
    } finally {
        if (null != conn) {
            conn.disconnect();
        }
    }
    System.gc();
    return responseBuilder.toString();
}


/**
 * @Param: map , takes in value in key val format
 */
private static String getQuery(final Map<String, String> mPostItems) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    boolean first = true;
    final Set<String> mKeys = mPostItems.keySet();
    for (String key : mKeys) {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            result.append("&");

        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(key, "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(mPostItems.get(key), "UTF-8"));
        Log.e("Key#",key+"#"+mPostItems.get(key));
    }
    return result.toString();
}
```